# Getting resource value with explicit localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, localization

With different resource files (*.resx), how can I retrieve localized values by giving explicit localization.

That is, normally I can directly reference the attribute with custom-tool-namespace.Resource.localizedAttribute.

The value it will give depends on what localization has been set to CurrentCulture (thread-wise). But unlike this, I'd like to hand the localization to the resource getter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you have multiple resource files:

```
Messages.resx
Messages.fr-FR.resx
...
Messages.xx-XX.resx
```

all containing some string value you could retrieve the value for a specific culture:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
string value = Messages.ResourceManager.GetString("SomeKey", culture);
```

and this will be independently of the value of the current thread culture.

Comment: Thank you, there was so many attributes that I didn't notice the Messages-object had also ResourceManager.

Answer (score 5):

Better practice is to use **nameof** to mantain intellisense and avoid typing errors

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
string value = Messages.ResourceManager.GetString(nameof(Messages.SomeKey), culture);
```